# Can't connect to SQL Server 2008 from IBM Websphere Application Server Customization Console

Tags: sql-server, websphere, application-server

I'm trying to install a IBM Websphere Operational Decision Management 8 in a Windows 2008 server with SQL Server 2008. I'm instaling in a clear instance of Websphere Application Server 8.

When I try to augment a clear Websphere Application Server profile with WODM 8, in the database step, I can't to connect to my SQL Server 2008. The Websphere Customization Console show the message:

" Database verification failed due to an exception.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver "

I'm using the Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server.

Can somebody help-me?

If needs more information I can to provide.

Tks!

Comment: any solution on this issue ? I am facing similar issue